# How do I open a file in its default program by using the CLI in GitBash on Windows 7?

Tags: file, command-line-interface, git-bash, default-programs

I'm currently using GitBash on Windows 7 to play around with the command line interface and would be very interested to know how to use GitBash to open a file/document in its default program.

Answer (score 34):

You can use `start` to open a file using its default application. For example:

```
start some-image.jpg
start some-document.pdf
```

Comment: On Windows 10 this just opens the command prompt for me.

Answer (score 10):

Start gives me permission issues on my work machine. However the `explorer` command works for me.

```
explorer some-image.jpg
```